# why am i getting different outputs when using replacefirst

Tags: regex

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
String a="/Construction/src/Inventory/PeportsUI/sql/inv_insert_crdtypedet_faultyprt_chk_typ_r3450.sql";
String b="/Construction/src/Inventory/UI/sql/inventory_query_update_Ciena.sql";
System.out.println(a.replaceFirst(".*/.[^(sql|plsql)]*/", ""));
System.out.println(b.replaceFirst(".*/.[^(sql|plsql)]*/", ""));
    }
```

for both i should be getting output AS

```
sql/inv_insert_crdtypedet_faultyprt_chk_typ_r3450.sql
sql/inventory_query_update_Ciena.sql
```

but instead i am getting following output

```
PeportsUI/sql/inv_insert_crdtypedet_faultyprt_chk_typ_r3450.sql
sql/inventory_query_update_Ciena.sql
```

why please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Your current regex has some problems.  It appears that you were trying to express *not* matching `sql` or `plsql` using the character class `[^(sql|plsql)]`.  But this won't work as intended, this actually means to not match any *character* inside the brackets.  If you wanted to go with that approach, you would have to use some sort of lookaround to do this.  However, I think a plain regex can be written, if phrased as below.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String a = "/Construction/src/Inventory/PeportsUI/sql/inv_insert_crdtypedet_faultyprt_chk_typ_r3450.sql";
    String b = "/Construction/src/Inventory/UI/sql/inventory_query_update_Ciena.sql";
    String c = "/Construction/src/Inventory/PeportsUI/plsql/inv_insert_crdtypedet_faultyprt_chk_typ_r3450.sql";
    System.out.println(a.replaceFirst(".*/((?:sql|plsql).*)", "$1"));
    System.out.println(b.replaceFirst(".*/((?:sql|plsql).*)", "$1"));
    System.out.println(c.replaceFirst(".*/((?:sql|plsql).*)", "$1"));
}
```

**Output:**

```
sql/inv_insert_crdtypedet_faultyprt_chk_typ_r3450.sql
sql/inventory_query_update_Ciena.sql
plsql/inv_insert_crdtypedet_faultyprt_chk_typ_r3450.sql
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: can you explain it to me why wasn't the first code working

Comment: I already explained, `[^(sql|plsql)]` does not do what you think.  My answer used a fixed pattern, but you could also have used a lookaround.

Comment: BUt why does this work when the length of the word before sql or plsql is less than 3 characters long as is the case in the string b i.e UI

Comment: It would not be efficient to explain the basics of regex in a series of comments.  Test your pattern and mine using a tool like [Regex101](http://www.regex101.com) and see how each one behaves.

Comment: thank you for your help.I have understood why wasn't i able to get the expected output